# bashにてファイル内のキーワードを参照し、文字列と共通する部分を抽出する方法

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript

【内容】
bashにて『キーワードが記載されたリスト（日本語、スペースあり、改行で区切り）』ファイルを参照し、与えた文字列（日本語、スペース・ハイフン等あり）とリストを比較して共通する部分を抽出し、与えた文字列の置換・変更に使いたいです。

【例】
キーワードが記載されたリスト (hoge_list)

```
東京都　中央区
東京都　目黒区
東京都　杉並区
神奈川県　横浜市
```

与える文字列 ($INPUT)

```
"東京都　杉並区　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3"
```

リスト内のキーワードと共通する部分が東京都　杉並区なので、その部分を抽出し

```
阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3
```

を出力したいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 与える文字列が例えば `東京都　墨田区　押上　1-4-2` の場合、期待される出力は何でしょうか？

Comment: その場合は該当する文字列がリストにないので、東京都　墨田区　押上　1-4-2の出力のままで大丈夫です。

Answer (score 1):

hoge_list を辞書のように使って、なんとかして一致するものを探してそれを削除… ということをしようとすると、かなり厄介なので、もっと単純に、

- 文字列の先頭が「東京都　中央区」だったらそれを削除
- 文字列の先頭が「東京都　目黒区」だったらそれを削除
- 文字列の先頭が「東京都　杉並区」だったらそれを削除
- 文字列の先頭が「神奈川県　横浜市」だったらそれを削除

という処理にします。

「一致したら削除」には sed を使うと便利です。

```
s|^東京都　中央区||
s|^東京都　目黒区||
s|^東京都　杉並区||
s|^神奈川県　横浜市||
```

という内容のファイルを hoge_list.sed という名前で作成しておき、

```
echo '東京都　杉並区　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3' | sed -f hoge_list.sed
```

と実行すると、

```
　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3
```

が得られます。

hoge_list は実際にはかなりの行数があるでしょうから、それを元に hoge_list.sed を作るのも自動化したいですよね。
その部分も含めてシェルスクリプトにまとめると、以下のようになります。

```
#!/bin/bash

cat hoge_list | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/s|^\1||/' > hoge_list.sed

sed -f hoge_list.sed | sed -e 's/^　//'
```

このスクリプトを test.sh という名前で保存し、実行すると、

```
$ echo '東京都　杉並区　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3' | ./test.sh
阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3
$
```

という出力が得られます。

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。無事解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

Awk を使ってみました。

```
$ INPUT='東京都　杉並区　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3'
$ awk -vinput="$INPUT" '
    input ~ "^"$0 {
      sub("^"$0"[ \t　]*", "", input)
      exit
    }END{ print input }
  ' hoge_list

阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3
```

Answer (score 0):

bashの機能だけで実現するなら以下のような感じだと思います。

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="東京都　杉並区　阿佐ヶ谷　1-2-3"
shopt -s extglob
list=$(<hoge_list)
pattern=${list//$'\n'/　|}
echo ${INPUT#@($pattern)}
```